# CRM 2015 How to read audit data in clear form?

Tags: dynamics-crm

How can I read from AuditBase using sdk 2015? How can I read the data in clear and understandable form?

Comment: If you want to create a SSRS report, [this blog describing for CRM 2011](http://kelvinshen.blogspot.de/2012/02/crm-2011-auditing-report.html) could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out these SDK functions, [Audit entity messages and methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328218.aspx)

- DeleteAuditDataRequestm Deletes all partitions containing audit data created before a given end date.
- RetrieveAttributeChangeHistoryRequest, Retrieves all changes to a specific attribute.
- RetrieveAuditDetailsRequest, Retrieves the full audit details of a particular audit record. The record to retrieve is specified in the AuditId property.
- RetrieveRequest, Retrieves an audit record. You can also call the IOrganizationService.Retrieve method.
- RetrieveMultipleRequest, Retrieves a collection of audit records. You can also call the IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple method.
- RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest, Retrieves all changes to a specific entity.

Comment: Trying to read from the AuditBase table will be painful. Each row contains a column with a delimited list of the fields that have changed and a column with a list of the previous field values.

The SDK functions listed above take away this pain by parsing the rows to a more usable format.